# Disable -ms-overflow-style "auto-hide" without disabling the bar completely

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, overflow

In IE11, my website bodies scrollbar keeps disappearing and re-appearing whenever the cursor goes into the page and out. I read that the IE-exclusive '-ms-overflow-style' CSS style is the problem. I set the following 2 CSS properties onto my body element:

```
body {
    -ms-overflow-style: none !important;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

I still want the scrollbar to appear when there is overflowing content which could vary depending on the browsers window height. I just don't want it to disappear and reappear in IE this "auto-hide" feature. Basically, I want it to behave the same as FF and Chrome.

Problem is, it seems that once I set '-ms-overflow-style' to 'none', IE11 ignores 'overflow-y' also. Very frustrating.

If my grammar is bad, sorry, I'm tired.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
-ms-overflow-style: scrollbar
```

Instead of `none`. Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441298.aspx